# Jupyter Notebook - Change HTTP Headers

Tags: jupyter

I am using jupyter notebook to host my machine learning codes and notebooks.

Jupyter Notebook server is sending some HTTP headers like Server = TornadoServer/5.1.1
I want to remove this header. Also want to add some HTTP headers like Cache-Control etc.
Can someone please tell me :

- What kind of Http server jupyter notebook runs
- Which configuration file controls the HTTP headers sent by Jupyter notebook
- Any link which explains how to change/add/remove the HTTP headers

Current jupyter notebook is running on Ubuntu server on https.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a config file in your home directory by running:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

which should leave you with a file `~/.jupyter`, called `jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

---

Have a look at all the possible configurations in [**the Jupyter documentation**](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html).

In addition to many server options, there is specifically an options to override Tornado configuration.

> NotebookApp.tornado_settings : Dict Default: {}
>
> Supply overrides for the tornado.web.Application that the Jupyter
>   notebook uses.

Comment: Thanks found it... I can add new headers.. How to change existing Server header? Should I just give some other value for this header?

Comment: I am afraid I do not know. It will depend on what you want to do - if you need more detail I would suggest posting the question on StackOverflow (and include more details about what you actually want to change).

Comment: Hi, The headers set by this method are not present when user is not logged in .. by default notebook opens as /tree? which does not contain these headers